# Is there a way to add custom rules to languageTool java API just by adding rule xml?

Tags: java, languagetool

Is there a way to add custom rules to languageTool java API just by appending rules to grammar.xml and keeping it external to the java project?

I want to deploy my java project only once, but keep updating the grammar rules whenever required. I would like to keep the xml file (say grammar.xml) separately from the project, and access it through java code.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to load XML rules with [PatternRuleLoader](https://languagetool.org/development/api/org/languagetool/rules/patterns/PatternRuleLoader.html) and then activate them using [JLanguageTool.addRule()](https://languagetool.org/development/api/org/languagetool/JLanguageTool.html). I'm not sure what will happen when you insert the same rule (i.e. a rule with the same id) more than once.